# sscanf copying data more than variable size

Tags: c, linux, scanf

I was running below code and trying to copy the data using **sscanf**.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char str[25]="";
char* str2="1234567890123456789012345678901234567";
sscanf(str2,"%s",str);
printf("str =%s,\nstr2=%s,\nsizeof(str)=%d",str,str2,sizeof(str));
return 0;
}
```

And below is the output I get:

```
str =1234567890123456789012345678901234567,
str2=1234567890123456789012345678901234567,
sizeof(str)=25
```

Can someone help me out why str is storing data more than its size.

gcc version 4.8.3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str` can only hold 25 characters. You tried to copy more than 25 characters into it. This causes undefined behaviour.

In C, the responsibility is on you to make sure that you only write to memory that you have allocated. If you don't follow the rules then there are no guarantees.

You could fix this code by using the format string `"%24s"` with `sscanf`.

Answer (score 3):

The C language does not check sizes of arrays. It is up to you to do that. When you copy str2 into str you are "invading" memory space that does not belong to str. What happens after the 25th char is undefined. (Luckily it was not yet modified because it's a short program but don't count on that!)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make str2 a bit longer. I extended it by 20 more digits and got a core dump, which was expected.

The reason why you were "successful" is that the compiler probably stored your values on some 2^n base for efficiency, so you got some extra bytes you didn't ask for.